# Is there a way to run experiment when it's located outside of folder containing main config?

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

So I have the following structure:

[image]

project_config.yaml is the main config file:

```
@hydra.main(config_path="configs/project_config", config_name="project_config.yaml")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))
```

Hovewer, when I try to run some_experiment.yaml like this:

```
python test.py +experiment_configs=some_experiments
```

it does't get found. The problem doesn't exist if I place experiment_configs folder inside project_config folder, however, I'd like the folder with experiments to be outside.
Is there a way to run experiment when it's located outside of project_config folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--config-dir` to add an additional directory to the config search path.
See `--hydra-help` or check the [docs](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/hydra-command-line-flags) here.